# unexpected opt-out

Tags: opt-out

One person has reported that they've received multiple opt out messages from civi even though they haven't requested to be opt-out from our emails. Is this happening to anyone else? What could be causing this issue and how I can I resolve it.

Comment: i have seen one instance on client using MS where the user must have marked it as spam, which resulted in it being sent to the admin address, who then unsubbed as they thought it was for them. i doubt this is what you are describing though